# Flask render_template doesnt return anything

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, google-drive-api

I created a webapp that gets an input search word, it searches a csv ad creates a new one. It dislays the new one as a table, with the first column being a button, that should open an image (unique for each row). With the press of each image it should pass the name of the image to flask and there i store it and make an api call to google drive and retrieve the image. The name is stored correctly and the api call works great, but it doesnt return anything neither a template nor just a text. The template is stored in the templates folder.

Here is the python code of the search results:

```python
@app.route('/search', methods=\['GET'\])
def search():
search_query = request.args.get('search_query')

    def search_word(word):
        i = 0
        l_rows = []
        for row in df.text:
            # Rows referring to blank pages are null
            if not isinstance(row, float) and word in row:
                if word in row:
                    d_rows = {"id": '<form action="/search" method="post" target="_blank"><input type="button" value="' + df.loc[i, "id"] + ' "id="seePage"></form>',
                              "period": df.loc[i, "period"], "committee": df.loc[i, "comitee"]}
                    l_rows.append(d_rows)
            i += 1
        new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(l_rows)
        html_table = new_df.to_html(classes='my-table', border=1, escape=False)
    
        return html_table
    
    search_word(search_query)
    
    return render_template("search_results.html", table=search_word(search_query))
```

Here is the htm code of the search results:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>Search Results</title>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
      {{table|safe}}
  </div>
  <script>
    var myButton = document.getElementById("seePage");
    myButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var url = "/image";
      var buttonText = this.value;
      var data = new URLSearchParams();
      data.append("buttonText", buttonText);
      fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: data
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
      })
      .then(function(text) {
        console.log(text);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is the python code for the image page:

```python
@app.route('/image', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def image_display():
    cell_value = request.form.get('buttonText')

    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']

    # Set the path to the client secret JSON file
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'cred_2.json'
    # Create the flow object and start the authorization flow
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES, redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:5000')

    credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Google Drive API setup

    if cell_value:
        def get_image(image):
            folder_id = 'the foder id'
            access_token = credentials.token
            print(f'access token f{access_token}')

            headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
            url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name="' + cell_value.strip() + '.jpg"+and+parents="' + folder_id + '"'
            print("URL: " + url)
            # Send request to Google Drive API
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            data = json.loads(response.content)
            print(f"data: {data}")
            # Get the download link of the first image with the matching name
            try:
                file_id = data['files'][0]['id']
                print(f'file id: {file_id}')
                image_url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=' + file_id
                print(f'image_url: {image_url}')
                return image_url
            except IndexError:
                print('except')
                return 'except'
        image_url = get_image(cell_value)
        if image_url != 'except':
            return render_template('image.html', cell_value=cell_value, image_url=image_url)
        else:
            return render_template('image.html', cell_value=cell_value, error_message='No matching image found')
    else:
        return 'ok'
```

Every file and folder is in the correct place. In this snippet i created the `get_image()` function, but i have also tried to just put it in the code without calling these lines as a function.
Finally here is the html code for the image.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Image\</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>ImageId: {{ cell_value }}</h1>
    {% if image_url %}
    <img src="{{ image_url }}" alt="{{ cell_value }}">
    {% endif %}
    {% if error_message %}
    <p class="error">{{ error_message }}</p>
    {% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

The return of the `image_display()` is nothing. Nevertheless it prints everything and the succeeds retrieving the correct url for the image.In the **console** of the browser [it shows the html code of image.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vZ5i.png) but it does not show the page.

---

What do i do wrong?

Comment: First, if 'image.html' really does contain those backslashes, take them out. Than, a simple way to diagnose this is to add a `@app.route('/test')` method that returns `render_template('image.html', cell_value=`test1', error_message='test'")`  No output from that? Then your template isn't in the right place. Unless you've done something special, it should be in a `templates/` directory in the root of the project.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith The backslashes  don't exist. Idon't know why it appears this way. The template is in the correct folder ( `templates/` ). Every other template that is there is accessed correctly. Finally i tried the test and it works. The template's folder is not the problem. As i said it returns nothing. Even if i asked to `return 'Success'` it won't do it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? If it doesn't even return 'Success' then you have problem in your fetch

Comment: @AbdullahAkçam Yes I 've tried debugging it. As i said it prints everything. For example in the try except handling it prints the `image_url` and the `file_id`. If i follow the image link it shows me the correct image. So everything is correct at this point. 
In the **console** of my browser it shows the tml code. But the page does not appear..